# php PDO binding issue

Tags: php, pdo

I m using php PDO as db connector. I am having problem in binding a email address
say i have an sql

```
$sql = UPDATE user set email = :email where uid = 10

$smt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$smt->bindParam(':email', 'xyz@gmail.com');
```

The PDO is leaving every thing after @.

Thanx

Comment: What do you mean by "leaving every thing after @"

Answer (score 5):

`bindParam` is used to bind a variable, not a value. I think what you want to do is use `bindValue` instead.

Comment: you answer is incorrect. In this case the stored procedure is related to an I/O parameter sending data (UPDATE). For this very reason, you should use bindParam and pass the parameter by reference to have it properly evaluated.

Comment: @cpugourou no, my answer is 100% correct. OP is trying to bind a value (the string `'xyz@gmail.com'`), but is using `bindParam`, which is meant for binding variables by reference. Changing this to `bindValue` will fix this. Quick example at https://3v4l.org/8kjBd to show the difference.

Answer (score -1):

```
define("SQLHOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("SQLUSER", "user");
define("SQLPASS", "password");
define("SQLSGBD", "database");

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . SQLHOST . ';dbname=' . SQLSGBD . ';charset=UTF8', SQLUSER, SQLPASS);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$emailList = ['xyz@gmail.com', 'abc@gmail.com'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE user set email = ? where uid = 10");
foreach ($emailList as $key => $email) {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $obj = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (count($obj) !== 0) {
        /* whatever */
    }
}
```